# setting file permissions with installshield limited edition

Tags: file-permissions, installshield-le

The installshield LE has deprecated features. Setting file permssions has been disabled. Is there a way to set file permssions. I tried running a post installation exe which uses icacls to set permissions but requires admin privileges to set permissions. Is there a way to grant admin privileges to setup installer. Or, is there a better way to do this.

Comment: I tried user2347457 solution but I was unable to make it work in a non-English Windows 10 with Installshield LE 2015. Installation log doesn't show any permission related action. In the end, the approach taken in this blog [Microsoft Installer: MSI](http://msiworld.blogspot.com.au/2008/11/different-ways-of-giving-permissions-in.html) using the "SECEDIT" solution probed to be fast and easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually edit the .isl file

Locate and entry like this:

```
<table name="File">
    <col key="yes" def="s72">File</col>
    <col def="s72">Component_</col>
    <col def="s255">FileName</col>
    <col def="i4">FileSize</col>
    <col def="S72">Version</col>
    <col def="S20">Language</col>
    <col def="I2">Attributes</col>
    <col def="i2">Sequence</col>
    <col def="S255">ISBuildSourcePath</col>
    <col def="I4">ISAttributes</col>
    <col def="S72">ISComponentSubFolder_</col>
    <row><td>myfile.sdf2</td><td>ISX_DEFAULTCOMPONENT6</td><td>LottoDB.sdf</td><td>0</td><td/><td/><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>C:\Users\Mauro\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MySolution\MayProject\MyFile.sdf</td><td>1</td><td/></row>
</table>
```

...where MyFile.sdf is the file whose permissions must be set.

Next, locate an entry like this (or add it):

```
<table name="ISLockPermissions">
    <col key="yes" def="s72">LockObject</col>
    <col key="yes" def="s32">Table</col>
    <col key="yes" def="S255">Domain</col>
    <col key="yes" def="s255">User</col>
    <col def="I4">Permission</col>
    <col def="I4">Attributes</col>
    <row><td>myfile.sdf2</td><td>File</td><td>[%USERDOMAIN]</td><td>Users</td><td>1610809791</td><td>0</td></row>
</table>
```

Note the the column Name in table File corresponds to column LockObject in table ISLockPermissions.

Permissions 1610809791 is "Write".

Answer (score 2):

Read my "Augmenting InstallShield"  blog series:

Here is one similar example:

[Augmenting InstallShield using Windows Installer XML - Certificates](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows.html)
[Augmenting InstallShield using Windows Installer XML - Windows Services](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows_19.html)

The concept is you leverage most of the free abilities of InstallShield Limited Edition along with injecting some additional free abilities of Windows Installer XML.  In this case you'd author a wxs file that has a Permissions element for the directory.  Once you build your MSM in WiX you add it to your ISLE project and associate it to a feature and directory. ( Right click the module and select properties then select INSTALLDIR from the drop down. )

Comment: This worked well for me. The thing that tripped me up was setting the Destination for the merge module in the Installshield Redistributables page to [INSTALLDIR] by right clicking on the new merge module and selecting properties. (note that the file permissions I was setting were in the install directory)

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by the limited edition.

A solution is to use a different setup authoring tool which allows setting file permissions or at least running deferred custom actions with no impersonation. Perhaps this list will help:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software